# Start program on Linux without user login

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have a program (written in Java, with *launch.sh* script) for Raspberry pi. I want it to start up automatically just as system boots up, but without needing anyone logging in to start it up.

Comment: Take a look at how system daemons are started. You can mimic that behavior. How exactly depends on the distribution you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add [`@reboot` crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry. It is executed regardless whether the user have logged in.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm :)

Comment: @Miku It does! One important thing is that it does not require root privileges to set up.